# What is the risk of RAID 0 for a *single* disk versus no RAID on that disk?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, raid0

I have a server that I'm having trouble with getting the drive to show up without using RAID. However, that's different question. This question is about the problems running a RAID 0 on a root drive in a server and what potential problems it could have versus not running RAID 0 on that same disk.

In this scenario, there is only 1 drive. There is a hardware RAID controller (Broadcom LSI 2208) built into the motherboard (server is Supermicro SuperServer 6017R-72RFTP with the motherboard [X9DRW-7TPF](https://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon/C600/X9DRW-7TPF.cfm)). The drive itself is a 1TB Samsung 860.

What potential disadvantages could there be in using RAID 0 on a single disk versus not using RAID on that same disk? My understanding is that there is a higher risk of catastophic data loss because now there are more components at play, and if the RAID array gets corrupted (like, due to power loss) then everything is lost, and other concerns. Is this correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you will need a similar, or even identical, RAID card do read the disk in another server. In other words: if your current server/motherboard/RAID card fails, you will need to buy another identical component.

To avoid that, and if your RAID card supports it, you should configure the RAID controller for *passthrough* operation (where disks are passed "as-is" to the operating system).

That said, any single disk storage will be inherently unreliable. If you can accept that, I see no real problem in using a RAID0 array over your single disk storage.

Comment: Thank you very much because I didn't know about that extremely major issue. Just another of many reasons NOT to use RAID.

Comment: Use cases for RAID style arrays exist. Replacement parts can be acquired. But with only a single physical disk, pass through or not using the hardware at all is simpler.

Comment: I solved the problem by disabling RAID in the BIOS. Fortunately, my BIOS had this option.